# Schema markup: Organization vs NewsMediaOrganization; Article vs NewsArticle

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

1) What is the difference between Organization and NewsMediaOrganization? We publish news on our site that are yet rarely but still get featured on top stories. We use Organization in our schema markup. Should we change it to NewsMediaOrganization? I've noticed that on few competitors pages.

2) Same story - Article or NewsArticle? Or even both?

Moreover, is it still true, that Google says, that Organization markup should remain only on home page?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between Organization and NewsMediaOrganization?

The type **[NewsMediaOrganization](https://schema.org/NewsMediaOrganization)** represents the organization of the news publisher and is a more specific type from the type **Organization**. Check the description of Schema about this type:

> A News/Media organization such as a newspaper or TV station.

==================================================================

> We publish news on our site that are yet rarely but still get featured
> on top stories. We use Organization in our schema markup. Should we
> change it to NewsMediaOrganization?

This is not a requirement, but it can help to represent your organization as a news publisher.

================================================================

> Moreover, is it still true, that Google says, that Organization markup
> should remain only on home page?

This is completely false information. Google has the **[following requirement for structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#relevance)** that you want to show in rich results:

> Relevance
>
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the
> page content.

Thus, the answer to your question "*Same story - Article or NewsArticle? Or even both?*" maybe the following:
If the main content of the web page is a simple article, then use the top-level type such as **Article**.
If the main content of the web page is a news article, then use the top-level type such as **NewsArticle**. However, using a top-level type of Article for a news article will not be a mistake, but it will have more general significance than a more specified type such as **NewsArticle**.